# What am I doing wrong in trying to create a model binder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this model:

```
public class QuestionSimple
    {
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public bool IsSingleChoice { get; set; }
        public List<String> Answers { get; set; }
        public string Difficutly { get; set; }
        public string Explanation { get; set; }

    }
```

Which I try to bind using this line in the `Global.asax.cs`

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(QuestionSimple), new AddQuestionSimpleBinder());
```

...With this binder

```
public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            // Get the raw attempted value from the value provider    
            string key = bindingContext.ModelName;
            ValueProviderResult val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);  
            //val is ALWAYS NULL
            return null;
        }
```

But val is alsways null.
Here is the View which should return (and actually does return) list of answers, when I'm **not** using my binder.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("AddQuestionSimple", "Topic", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "mainForm" }))
    {    
        <input type="text" name="questionToBeAdded.Answers[0]" value="ff" />
        <input type="text" name="questionToBeAdded.Answers[1]" value="ddds" />
        <input type="text" name="questionToBeAdded.Answers[2]" value="ff" />
        <input type="text" name="questionToBeAdded.Answers[3]" value="ddds" />
        <input type="text" name="questionToBeAdded.Answers[4]" value="ff" />
        <input type="text" name="questionToBeAdded.Answers[5]" value="ddds" /> 
        <input value="Add question" type="submit" style="position: static; width: 10em; height: 3em;
            font-size: 1em;" />
    }
```

The default model-binder does get my values when I post them, but my `val` is always `null`.
Why is that so?
(should mention this is a try of solving [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116795/adding-hidden-input-breaks-textarea-binding) bigger problem).

**Edit 1:**
Here is the supposed to be bound action

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult AddQuestionSimple(PMP.WebUI.Models.UserInteractionEntities.UserInput.QuestionSimple questionToBeAdded)
    {
        return View("AddQuestion");
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to override the BindModel, so your method would begin with:

```
public override object BindModel
```

Next, you won't find a value with the key "questionToBeAdded" in your `bindingContext.ValueProviders`.  Debug and look at that collection, bindingContext.ValueProviders[1] has a FormValueProvider that has all the properties of your model in there.  The way you're doing it, you might have to iterate through that manually.  Another way to do it is just to override the BindProperty method, just type:

```
protected override void BindProperty
```

In your model binder class and you'll get the method signature filled in (assuming you're inheriting from DefaultModelBinder).  In this method you'll get more detail about each property, the piping is done for you.

Comment: 'public override object BindModel' gives compile time error- no suitable method to overrided. (I'm implementing IModelBinder). Should also mention that the debugger did got to my binder without using "override", and 'bindingContext.ValueProviders[1]' gives: ...ModelBindingContext does not contain a definition for 'ValueProviders'..

Comment: Oh yeah, I was assuming you're inheriting from DefaultModelBinder.  If not, just ignore the override modifier.  But I suggest you inherit DefaultModelBinder to get you started with custom binders.